# Make manifest file from imperative command

Tags: kubernetes, export, manifest, declaration, imperative

I am reading on `k8s` it has 2 method to use it. Both of them are complement of each other.

Today I tried one feature to get a declarative (manifest file).

Suppose I create `namespace` instance

```sh
$ kubectl create namespace cert-manager
namespace/cert-manager created
```

Then I export the manifest file for using declarative method next time

`kubectl get namespace cert-manager -o yaml --export > cert-manager.yaml`

`cert-manager.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: cert-manager
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/cert-manager
spec:
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes
status:
  phase: Active
```

Compare with other example

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
```

**Question**

Is 2nd shorter manifest file correctly done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your 2nd manifest file is correct.

The `spec` describes your desired state for the object–the characteristics that you want the object to have. The `status` describes the actual state of the object, and is supplied and updated by the Kubernetes system.

`Namespace` object has only one optional field `finalizers`, which allows observables to purge resources whenever the namespace is deleted.

So, the simplest [namespace manifest file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/namespaces/#creating-a-new-namespace) is the following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: <namespace-name>
```